# Show that a set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is invertible and {v1, ... , vk} is linearly independent set in R^n, 
show {Av1, ..., Avk} is also linearly independent.

A is nxn square matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $\{Av_1,...,Av_k\}$ is not linearly independent, then $Av_1=a_2(Av_2)+...+a_k(Av_k)$, where $a_i$ are scalars from the field and not all $a_i$ are equal $0$. but then

$$Av_1=A(a_2v_2+...+a_kv_k)$$ muliplying by $A^{-1}$ we get $v_1=a_2v_2+...+a_kv_k$ and $\{v_i\}$ for a set that is not linearly independent.

Comment: Why from $\;\{Av_1,...,Av_k\}\;$ being lin. ind. it follows that $\;Av_1\;$ **precisely** is a lin. combination...of itself and the other elements?! This seems to be wrong and not always true.

Comment: Indeed, the right hand side should start with $a_2(Av_2)$. My misteake.

Comment: @pw Also that is wrong: a (finite, for simplicity) set of vectors is linearly *dependent* iff there is one that is a linear combination of the preceeding ones. You can change "preceeding" by proceeding and it still will be correct, yet you cannot in general decide that it is **precisely** the first vector which is a linear comb. of the following ones. For example, the set $\;\{(1,0),\,(0,1),\,(0,2)\}\;$ is a lin. dep. set, yet it is **not true** that the first vector is a lin. comb. of the last two. This answer still is wrong, yet it doesn't really matter: the OP already chose it.

Comment: You are right but without loss of generality we may assume that the first vector is the one that is a linear combination of the others. But thanks for correction. I should've written it a little more precisely.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\alpha_1(Av_1)+\alpha_2(Av_2)+\dots+\alpha_k(Av_k)=0$. Then
$$
A(\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_kv_k)=0
$$
by the properties of matrix product. Then, multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$ gives
$$
A^{-1}A(\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_kv_k)=A^{-1}0
$$
or
$$
\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_kv_k=0
$$
Then $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\dots=\alpha_k=0$ by the linear independence of $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$.

Comment: As simple as that...yet the OP chose an answer that looks wrong. Oh, well. +1

Comment: @Timbuc Let's wait until the TA will grade the OP's homework.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Suppose not. Than there is a not-all-zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k x_i Av_i = 0,
$$
or in other words if $V = [v_1 \ldots v_k]$ then $AV \vec{x} = 0$.
Take inverses -- what can you say about$V$?